# Check if date match with format using momentjs

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I try to check if a date match with format using momentjs. But I have error when date include time zone.

Example:

```
moment('Mon Nov 10 2016 14:53:17', 'ddd MMM DD YYYY HH:mm:ss', true).isValid()
```

in this case the response is true without errors.
but in this other case, I not found the correct date format to compare

```
moment('Mon Nov 10 2016 14:53:17 GMT-0500 (ECT)', '?????', true).isValid()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can split your string in `GTM-..` place and take only part before. Below is example, `split()` just splitting the string and return array, so first part of string (before `GTM`) will be at zero index.

```
var data = 'Mon Nov 10 2016 14:53:17 GMT-0500 (ECT)';
moment(date.split(' GMT')[0], 'ddd MMM DD YYYY HH:mm:ss', true).isValid()
```

It works for strings without `GTM` part too, because it will return just one-element array with whole string.

Comment: Please add some explanation of why this code helps the OP. This will help provide an answer future viewers can learn from. See [answer] for more information.

Comment: Really the response resolve partially my problem. But I need make additional work. The most correct procedure that I was want is a way to check the timezone. But I select as ok your response becouse with some work I can resolve my situation.